# How to make the activated specific runner of gitlab working?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My job is pending and get below message:

> This job is stuck, because you don't have any active runners that can run this job.

[image: stuck]

But I do have an activated runner available for this project:

[image: active]

The runner is installed as docker in one of my vps:

[image]

[image]

Below is the config for this runner:

concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

```
[[runners]]
  name = "ansible"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "xxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/artwater/ansible:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
```

below is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - production

job_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ansible-playbook -i ./ansible/hosts/production.yml --extra-vars "version=$CI_BUILD_TAG" ./ansible/build.yml
  only:
    - tags

job_production:
  stage: production
  script:
    - ansible-playbook -i ./ansible/hosts/production.yml --extra-vars "version=$CI_BUILD_TAG" ./ansible/deploy.yml
  only:
    - tags
  when: on_success
```

Can anyone please let me know how can I make this runner working? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems to be a problem introduced with GitLab 9.0, we experience the same problem after update on a local installation.

Further do we see the problem also with enabled shared runners.

Comment: Crosslink to Issue on GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/29928

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you need to either specify for the project which uses your runner the respective **tag** (e.g. ansible in your example) or enable the runner to not check tags: Run untagged jobs (at least for shared runners)

Comment: How do you specify project's tags?

Answer (score 2):

Try the untagged run. Go to the specific runner configuration in GitLab instance and check "Run untagged jobs" and resubmit the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any issues with gitlab-runner try the following command to debug. You'll get more information about where things are going wrong.

```
sudo gitlab-runner -debug run
```

Mention tags in pipeline stage, if runner is not untagged type and you can edit runner configuration in gitlab runner edit form.

Specifically, runner checks for jobs; sometime runner's job will be in pending because it fails to detect job.

After running the debug command runner job starts quickly if the configuration is correct.